# Suballocating memory block

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am working with a network API that returns a list of 1 or more messages into a buffer I provide it. A typical buffer looks like this upon return:

`|B|message 1|S|message 2|S|message 3|E|`

Where |B| is a character indicating begin, |S| is a separator, and |E| is the end. The messages can be of varying length and number. What I would like to do is traverse this buffer once and split it into its (in this case) 3 component messages, and send something like a `std::unique_ptr<char*>` out to code that will process each individual message, and let the unique_ptr take care of releasing the memory. But I'd like to do so without copying these messages out of their buffer and into smaller ones.

Is there a technique I can use to, effectively, sub-allocate the buffer into new, smaller heap blocks and still get the benefit of automatic cleanup?

Comment: Lookup for placement new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such a thing as "suballocating" a buffer, at least for most implementations of allocation mechanisms (i.e. heaps).

As a simple solution I'd suggest you to work with *shared* pointer to the whole buffer, plus the pointer (or offset) and size of the found message.

That is, something like this.

```
struct MsgPtr
{
    shared_ptr<Buffer> m_Buf;
    char* m_pMsg;
    size_t m_nMsgSize;
};
```

This should be ok in case you don't intend to keep the parsed messages in memory for a long time.

Comment: This is a good idea. Taking it a step further, I wonder if constructor form (8) of the shared_ptr might do just what I need. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr